# How do I solve 'The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.' error in Django?

Tags: python, django

The view didn't return an Httpresponse object. It returned None instead.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy3QL.png)

I am getting "The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."
When I clicked on edit button its giving me error

url.py:

```
urlpatterns=[
    
    path("client",views.client,name="client"),
    path("show_client/<str:pk>",views.show_client,name="show_client"),
    path("client_edit",views.client_edit,name="edit_client"),
]
```

views.py:

```
def show_client(request,pk):
    
    a_url = ""
    payload = json.dumps({
        "grant_type": "client_credentials"
    })
    elastic_api_key=""

    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Apikey ' + elastic_api_key,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    auth_response = requests.request("POST", a_url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    auth_response_json = auth_response.json()
    # print(auth_response_json)
    access_token = auth_response_json['access_token']
    print(access_token)
    url = ""
   
    payload = ""
    headers = {
    'Authorization': "Bearer " + access_token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
    res_data = response.json()
    dt = res_data['hits']['hits']
```

html:
client.html:

```
       <table id="order-listing" class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Customer Name</th>
                            <th>Jira Id</th>
                            <th>Time zone</th>
                            <th>Signed Date</th>
                          
                            <th>Action</th>
                            
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                   
                      <tbody>
   
                      {% for i in data_lst %}
                        <!-- {{i.organization_name}} -->
                       
                        
                         <tr>
                       
                            <td>{{i.organization_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{i.organization_id}}</td>
                            <td>{{i.timezone}}</td>
                            <td>{{i.signed_date}}</td>
                            <td>
                              <a href="{% url 'show_client' i.organization_name %}" style="border: 1px solid gray;padding:10px;color:#4bda2f;outline-style:none"><i class="fa fa-eye"> View</i></a>&nbsp;
                              <a href="" style="border: 1px solid gray;padding:10px;color:#eb2805;">Delete</a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                       
                  
                        
                      {%endfor%}                          
               
                    
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
```

```
    for i in dt:
        
        customer_dt =i
        customer = customer_dt['_source']['customer']
   
        if pk == customer['organization']['organization_name']:
            # print("---^^organization^^----",customer['organization'])
            org = customer['organization']
          
           
            poc=customer['contacts'][0]['port53']
          
            client = customer['contacts'][1]['customer']
       
            services = customer['services'][0]['socaas']
           
            crtical_assets = customer['criticalAssets'][0]['VMs']
            print(crtical_assets)


            context={'org':org,'poc':poc,'client':client,'services':services,'vm':crtical_assets}


            return render(request,"show_client.html",context)
```

```
show_client.html
<form action="client_edit" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <!-- ####################################### organization ##################################### -->
            <div class="row" style="border:1px solid rgb(101, 98, 98);padding:20px;border-radius:10px;">

              <h5 class="heading">Organization</h5>
              <hr>

              <div class="col ">
                <label for="org_id" class="org_label">Organization ID</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="org_id" name="org_id" value="{{org.organization_id}}" placeholder="organization id">
              </div>
              <div class="col ">
                <label for="org_name" class="org_label">Organization Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="orga_name" name="org_name" value="{{org.organization_name}}" placeholder="organization name">
              </div>
              <div class="col ">
                <label for="timezone" class="org_label">Timezone</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="timezone" name="timezone" value="{{org.timezone}}" placeholder="timezone">
                
              </div>

            </div>
            <!-- ############################## end of organization ########################################### -->

            <!-- ################################### Controls ######################################################## -->
            <div class="control-services" style="padding-top: 20px;">
              
              
            </div>

            <!-- #################################### end of controls ################################################ -->
            <!-- ######################################### Contact ################################################### -->
            <div class="contact-detail" style="padding-top: 20px;">  
              <div class="row" style="border:1px solid rgb(101, 98, 98);padding:20px;border-radius:10px">
                <h5 class="heading">Controls</h5>
                <hr>
                <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid rgb(83, 85, 84);margin:0.5px;">
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                      <div style="margin-top: 8px;">
                          <h6>Point of Contact(Port53)</h6>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                      
                  </div>
                </div>
                <table>
                  
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Email</th>
                      <th>Phone</th>
                      <th>Mobile</th>
                      <th>Role</th>
                      <th>Title</th>
                      <th>Is_primary</th>
                        
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  {% for i in poc%}
                  <tr>
                    
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="poc_name" name="poc_name" value="{{i.name}}" placeholder="name"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="poc_email" name="poc_email" value="{{i.email}}" placeholder="email"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="poc_phone" name="poc_phone" value="{{i.phone}}" placeholder="phone"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="poc_mobile" name="poc_mobile" value="{{i.mobile}}" placeholder="mobile"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="poc_role" name="poc_role" value="{{i.role}}" placeholder="role"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="poc_title" name="poc_title" value="{{i.title}}" placeholder="role"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="poc_primary" name="poc_primary" value="{{i.is_primary}}" placeholder="role"></td>
                   
                  </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid rgb(83, 85, 84);margin:0.5px;">
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                      <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
                          <h6>Client Contact Details</h6>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                     
                  </div>
                  <table>
                  
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Mobile</th>
                        <th>Role</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Is_primary</th>
                          
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for dt in client %}
                   
                    <tr>
                      
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="c_name" name="c_name" value="{{dt.name}}" placeholder="name"></td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="c_email" name="c_email" value="{{dt.email}}" placeholder="email"></td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="c_phone" name="c_phone" value="{{dt.phone}}" placeholder="phone"></td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="c_mobile" name="c_mobile" value="{{dt.mobile}}" placeholder="mobile"></td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="c_role" name="c_role" value="{{dt.role}}" placeholder="role"></td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="c_title" name="c_title" value="{{dt.title}}" placeholder="title"></td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="c_primary" name="c_primary" value="{{dt.is_primary}}" placeholder="is_primary"></td>
                     
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- ####################################### end of contact ############################################## -->
               
                <div class="services" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                  <div class="row" style="border:1px solid rgb(101, 98, 98);padding:12px;font-size:12px;">
                  <div class="row">
                  

                      <h5 class="heading">Critical Assets(VMs)</h5>
                      <hr>
  
                      <div class="col ">
                        <label for="assests_name" class="org_label">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Name" id ="asset_name" name="as_name" value="{{vm.name}}">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col ">
                        <label for="assests_type" class="org_label">Type</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Type" id ="assets_type" name="assets_type" value="{{vm.type}}">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col ">
                        <label for="assets_add" class="org_label">IP Address</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="IP address" name="assets_ip" value="{{vm.ip_address}}">
                      </div>
  
                    </div>

                    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                      <div class="col-md-4 ">
                        <label for="contact" class="org_label">Contact</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="contact" id="assets_contact" name="assets_contact" value="{{vm.contacts}}">
                      </div>


                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>

                <!-- ####################################### end of critical assets ################################################# -->
                


            <div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="color:white;border:1px solid rgb(35, 95, 173);margin-top:20px;">Submit</button>
              <!-- <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="color:white;border:1px solid rgb(35, 95, 173);margin-top:20px;" > -->
            </div>
          </form>
```

Comment: Seems right on point, this error message. Your view function does not have a return statement.

Answer (score 0):

You say you can display your view 'show_client' without problem, right? But when you try to go to 'client_edit', it throws an error?

In your error, it says the url you are trying to go to is 'show_client/client_edit', but from your urls it seems the correct url would just be 'client_edit'.

Try changing the first line of show_client.html to this:

```
<form action="/client_edit" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Your form action was `action="client_edit"` instead of `action="/client_edit"`. The slash matters. If you don't have it, it will just append to the URL you are already at instead of the base URL. Now when you submit the form it should direct you to the right url.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your view is `return`ing by falling off the end of its code, rather than returning an HttpResponse object.

If the view code (show_client) you posted is not accidentally truncated, the problem is that it doesn't end with `return HttpResponse( ...)`. Not sure whether `response` in your code is such an object. If it is, it needs to be returned.